# Specify different Boost location in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, boost, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

For a bunch of reasons (compatibility and functionality), I need to be able to specify a different location for the Boost headers.

So, instead of `/usr/include`, (default) I want *rosmake* to look FIRST in `/my/example/path` for inclusions of the style `#include <boost/someheader.hpp>` How can I do this???

Thanks a lot in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173561/specify-different-boost-location-in-cmakelists.txt/) by [sanchises](https://answers.ros.org/users/18785/sanchises/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/module/FindBoost.html) of `FindBoost.cmake` on the CMake site (you can also read this in the file itself):

```
This module reads hints about search locations from variables:

BOOST_ROOT                - Preferred installation prefix (or BOOSTROOT)
BOOST_INCLUDEDIR          - Preferred include directory e.g. <prefix>/include
BOOST_LIBRARYDIR          - Preferred library directory e.g. <prefix>/lib
Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS     - Set to ON to disable searching in locations not
                            specified by these hint variables. Default is OFF.
Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS - List of Boost versions not known to this module
                            (Boost install locations may contain the version)
```

So additional Boost locations can be specified by setting the variable `BOOST_ROOT` variable. This can be done either in the `CMakeLists.txt` (be sure to check how this influences included / downstream build scripts) or from the command line using `-DBOOST_ROOT=/some/path`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1